# Azure Data Factory Stop 2 triggers from executing at same time

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory

I have two ADFv2 triggers.

One is set to execute every 3 mins and another every 20 mins.

They execute different pipelines but there is an overlap as both touch the same database table which I want to prevent.

Is there a way to set them up so if one is already running and the other is scheduled to start, it is instead queued until the running trigger is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Not natively AFAIK.  You can use the pipeline's concurrency property setting to get this behaviour but only for a single pipeline.

Instead you could (we have):

- Use Validation activity to block if a sentinel blob exists and have your other pipeline write and delete the blob when it starts/ends.
- Likewise have one pipeline set a flag in a control table on the database that you can examine
- If you can tolerate changing your frequencies to have a common factor, create a master pipeline that Execute Pipeline's your current two pipelines; make the longer one only called every *n*-th run using MOD.  Then you can use the concurrency setting on the outer pipeline to make sure the next trigger gets queued until the current run ends.
- Use REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically#rest-api in one pipeline to check if the other is running

Answer (score 0):

Jason's post gave me an idea for a more simple solution.

I have two triggers.  Each executes at different schedules and different pipelines.
On occasion the schedule on these triggers can overlap.  In this circumstance the trigger that fires while the other is running should not run. Only one to be running at any one time.

I did this using the following.

Create a control table with a `IsJobRunning BIT` (flag) column

When a trigger fires, the pipeline associated with it will execute an SP that will check the Control table.

If the value in the `IsJobRunning` is 0 then `UPDATE` the `IsJobRunning` column to 1 and continue executing,

if 1 then `RAISEERROR` - a dummy error - stop executing.

```
IF (SELECT J.IsJobRunning FROM '[[Control table ]]' ) = 1 
BEGIN 
    SET @ERRMSG         = N'**INFORMATIONAL ONLY** Other ETL trigger job is running - so stop this attempt ' ; 
    SET @ErrorSeverity = 16 ; 
        -- Note: this is only a INFORMATIONAL message and not an actual error. 
    RAISERROR (@ERRMSG,@ErrorSeverity,1 ) WITH NOWAIT; 
    RETURN 1; 
END ; 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
        -- set @IsJobRunning to RUNNING 
    EXEC '[[ UPDATE IsJobRunning on COntrol table]] '    ;  
END ;
```

This looks like this in the pipeline.

[image]

This logic is in both Pipelines.